# Get all actions of the last three users

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a history table that stores all actions done by users on deferments posts

```
    id     | post_id | action    |  user_id
    1      |  5      | 1         |  3
    2      |  6      | 4         |  1
    3      |  6      | 4         |  4
    4      |  7      | 2         |  6
    5      |  7      | 3         |  2
    6      |  5      | 2         |  3
    7      |  4      | 5         |  3
```

What I want is to get all actions done by the last three users

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: what is the result that you want based on the example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `ID` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column,

```
SELECT  a.user_ID, a.action
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  DISTINCT user_ID
            FROM    tableName   
            ORDER   BY ID DESC
            LIMIT   3
        ) b ON user_ID = b.user_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d153/3)