# Get all actions of the last three users for each post

Tags: mysql, sql

In a [last Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879676/get-all-actions-of-the-last-three-users), i asked about geting all actions of the last three users from a history table that stores all actions done by users on deferments posts, now what i want is to get the same thing but **for each post**.

***all actions of the last three users for each posts***

```
history table
     id     | post_id | action    |  user_id
     1      |  5      | 1         |  3
     1      |  23     | 2         |  1
     2      |  24     | 2         |  6
     3      |  34     | 1         |  7
     4      |  35     | 1         |  1
     5      |  36     | 1         |  1
     6      |  23     | 2         |  3
     7      |  24     | 2         |  1
     8      |  23     | 1         |  4
     9      |  24     | 1         |  5
     10     |  24     | 1         |  1
     11     |  23     | 1         |  2
     12     |  23     | 4         |  1
```

thanks and sorry if it seem to be a duplicate post

Answer (score 1):

This is a query that requires lots of self joins:

```
select hl.post_id, h.*
from history h join
     (select h.*, count(*) as NumLater
      from history h join
           history h2
           on h.post_id = h2.post_id and
              h2.id >= h.id
      group by h.id
      having NumLater <= 3
     ) hl
     on h.user_id = hl.user_id
order by hl.post_id
```

The inner query does a self join to calculate the number of history entries after each record in the same post.  The join then joins this by user_id to the history table.  This version does *not* eliminate duplicates.  So, a user could be in the last-three set for two different posts.

Comment: You just have to modify your query so each post id has a different name . . . `a.post_id as a_post_id`.

Comment: Sorry i'm confused, your query don't work like it should, it bring many duplicated **history.id**, [here is the result of your query](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d54d3/3/0), sorry again I'm a HTML designer, database are my weak point

Comment: @cool-man . . . It is bringing back duplicated `history.id`, because that column contains duplicates in the original table.  I'm guessing this is a design flaw.