# Get all actions of the last-three users for each post

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

In a [last Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879676/get-all-actions-of-the-last-three-users), i asked about geting all actions of the last three users from a history table that stores all actions done by users on deferments posts, now what i want is to get the same thing but **for each post**.

***all actions of donne by the last-three users for each posts***

```
history table
     id     | post_id | action    |  user_id
     1      |  5      | 1         |  3
     1      |  23     | 2         |  1
     2      |  24     | 2         |  6
     3      |  34     | 1         |  7
     4      |  35     | 1         |  1
     5      |  36     | 1         |  1
     6      |  23     | 2         |  3
     7      |  24     | 2         |  1
     8      |  23     | 1         |  4
     9      |  24     | 1         |  5
     10     |  24     | 1         |  1
     11     |  23     | 1         |  2
     12     |  23     | 4         |  1
```

thanks and sorry if it seem to be a duplicate post

Comment: You want to get the last 3 users of each post?

Comment: No ! what i want is getting all actions donne by the last-three users for each posts, thanks

Comment: Ok, I made a change to my query.  If I'm understanding your requirements correctly, for each post, you want the last 3 users (different users per post), with all their actions.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
SELECT  a.user_ID, a.post_id, a.action
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  DISTINCT 
              @curRow:=IF(@prevRow=post_Id,@curRow+1,1) rn,
              user_ID, 
              Post_Id, 
              @prevRow:=Post_Id
            FROM    (
                SELECT DISTINCT Post_Id, User_Id
                FROM TableName
                ORDER   BY Post_Id, ID DESC 
              ) t  
              JOIN (SELECT @curRow:= 0) r

        ) b ON a.post_id = b.post_id AND a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE b.rn <= 3
ORDER   BY a.post_id, a.User_ID
```

And the [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f899e1/11).

Comment: I just don't get it ! It perfectly work in the fiddle, but it don't give the same result on my server, i work on wamp server 2.2, mysql version 5.5.24

Answer (score 0):

Coudl this be what you are looking for?

- [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d153/13)

Code:

```
SELECT  a.user_ID,
group_concat(a.post_id),
group_concat(a.action)
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  DISTINCT user_ID
            FROM    tableName   
            ORDER   BY ID DESC
            LIMIT   3
        ) b ON a.user_ID = b.user_ID
group by a.user_id
ORDER   BY a.User_ID;


| USER_ID | GROUP_CONCAT(A.POST_ID) | GROUP_CONCAT(A.ACTION) |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|       2 |                       7 |                      3 |
|       3 |                   5,5,4 |                  1,2,5 |
|       6 |                       7 |                      2 |
```

Comment: You can remove `group_concat` if you want to expand the table rows for *all actions for **last-three** users for each posts*..

Comment: @cool-man -- why does it need to work with postgresql?  You tagged your question MySQL?  Which DB is it???

Comment: @cool-man since you have asked the tree of these two related questions in MYSQL, we have provided the answer in MYSQL. In order to work it with postgres, you can try with `array_agg` by replacing `group_concat`..

Comment: I project to move from  mysql to postgresql  in a near future, so i'm just   wondering if it's compatible or not

Comment: The above query is compatible when replaced with `array_agg`. Try in postgres of sqlfiddle you will know :)

Comment: Sorry, this isn't the query that i need, your query bring the results for each users, what i want is for each post all actions done by the three-last users